# SOAP Server side certificate verification on PHP

Tags: php, soap, x509

Previously I have created system that was sending SOAP messages using certificate.

Example shows how it was done:

```
$client_options = array();
$client_options['local_cert'] = '<path to .pem file>';
$client_options['passphrase'] = '<.pem file password>';
$client = new SoapClient('<address to wsdl file>', $client_options);

$tmp_res = $client->some_function($params);
```

But now I have to create server that receives messages like these.

I found many resources, all suggesting this code:

```
$classmap = array('<class_name2>'=>'<class_name2>');
$server = new SoapServer('<path to wdsl file>',array('classmap'=>$classmap));
$server->setClass("<class_name>");
$server->handle();
```

Code itself works, but what I can't understand is - how certificates work within this client-server communication.

- As I understand, for secure communication two pairs of private key and certificate are required. One for each of parties.
- There is way to add .pem file with one private key and certificate pair for `SoapClient`.
- Incoming messages (at the both sides) comes unencrypted.

.

1. Mustn't there be a way to pass certificate and key pair for `SoapServer`?
2. How exactly verification of certificates are performed (at what point and what is checked)?
3. How I can filter out messages only from the user I'm interested in, provided, I can get his certificate?

Sorry for such childish questions, but can You point me out, where I am wrong and provide appropriate resources to find information about this?

Thanks.